# Using the "..." argument in functions in C with no headers

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64

I'm creating my own kind of C library with my own kind of functions and also to help be better understand C and not just depend on GNU C Library for everything.

So far I got a bit of functions running but I wan't to tweak my printo function a little bit to support unlimited arguments (Restricted to chars only but your answer may also support passing in integer arguments). Here is the printo code:

```
#include "../GV.h"
#include "OtherUtils.h"

int print(char *WRITEOUT1){
  char *WRITEOUT=&WRITEOUT1[0];
  int AMOUNT=GetCharSize(WRITEOUT1);

  register int SYSCALLNO asm("rax")=SYSWRITE;
  register int FD asm("rdi")=STANDARDFD;
  register char *BUF asm("rsi")=WRITEOUT;
  register int BYTES asm("rdx")=AMOUNT;
  asm("syscall");

  return 0;
}
```

GetCharSize function code if anyone needs it:

```
#include "../GV.h" 

int GetCharSize(char *arg){
  for(i=0;arg[i]!='\0';i++){
  }
  return i;
}
```

GV.h has variables defined like `int i;`

Before I asked this question I looked into C pre-processors like `__VA_ARGS__` but I somewhat couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Search for "variadic functions".  Lot's of examples.  `man vfprintf` for some examples.

Comment: Unrelated, but: 1) there already exist minimalistic `printf` implementations you can use instead of reinventing the wheel ([printf](https://github.com/mpaland/printf), [tinyprintf](https://github.com/cjlano/tinyprintf)). 2) going down to the assembler level is most likely a huge overkill. Profile, then optimize the 20% code which is responsible for 80% of your running time. Everything else is just burning someone's money. 3) I hope `i` is not a global variable inside `GV.h`?

Comment: *"GV.h has variables defined like int i;"* - sorry but you're doing it utterly horribly wrong. That variable **has to be a local variable within the function**

Comment: The argument passing in C is "by magic", though there is an ABI. It is not possible to code against the ABI in C - the only thing you can use are the variadic functions in C and with the help of `<stdarg.h>` only.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I was able to do it lol without variadic and stdarg.h

Comment: @Fitz lol at your undefined behaviour. It **will** break without any notice. Specifically you're now understanding C even less, if possible.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Everything breaks at one point, its broken for yourself to fix it. I'm only 13 let me explore every possibility of this world. Then one day I would become an expert and CEO like you in the future.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala anyway, how do I understand C more then? (Not trying to doubt you response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `...` notation is a part of the syntax of the C language. It is used in defining the argument list of a function as the last argument and means "followed by zero or more arguments of any type". E.g.

```
int printf (char *format, ...);
```

A function defined in this way can now be called with all the mandatory arguments, plus any number of additional arguments, like `printf`.

A function defined is this way must have a means of knowing how many arguments there are, and what the type of each argument is. `printf` knows this from the *format specification string*, the only required argument of `printf`.

Assuming an Intel system that uses a stack to pass arguments, and where arguments are pushed right-to-left (last argument pushed first), so the *first*  optional argument will be directly *after* the format specification string on the stack, `printf` now proceeds as follows: take the address of the format specfication string and increment that address with the size of a char *. This is the start of the optional arguments. Now look at the format specifier string to know the type of the next argument; get that type of argument from the stack, increment it with the size of that argument to get the next address. Do this until there are no more format specifiers.

Comment: It does not *really* help OP though because OP's code targets x86-64, and there stack won't be used.

Comment: aye your explanation worked, i really appreciate it.

Comment: To generalize from "stack" to modern calling conventions like x86-64 System V, printf takes an input from the next "arg passing slot", whether that's an integer register, or the stack if it's already gone through the first 6 integer/pointer args.